# How to extract substring between two keywords with exceptional cases?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract substring between `apple` and `each` in a string. However, if `each` is followed by `box`, I want the result be an empty string.

In details, it means:

1)`apple costs 5 dollars each` -> `costs 5 dollars`

2)`apple costs 5 dollars each box` -> ``

I tried `re.findall('(?<=apple)(.*?)(?=each)'))`.

It can tackle 1) but not 2).

How to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: if you want it with regex. I will delete my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a negative lookahead, asserting what is on the right is not  `box`. For a match only you can omit the capturing group.

```
(?<=apple).*?(?=each(?! box))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ecvN3C/1)

If you don't want to match the leading space, you could add that to the lookarounds

```
import re
s = "apple costs 5 dollars each"
print(re.findall(r'(?<=apple ).*?(?= each(?! box))', s))
```

Output

```
['costs 5 dollars']
```

---

You can also use a capturing group without the positive lookaheads and use the negative lookahead only. The value is in the first capturing group.

You could make use of word boundaries `\b` to prevent the word being part of a larger word.

```
\bapple\b(.*?)\beach\b(?! box)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fmeaQJ/1)

Comment: It works. Thank you, The fourth bird. BTW, why are you called the fourth bird?

Comment: @Chan An old colleague of mine chose `three litte birds` as a name for one of his projects.

Answer (score 2):

try this without using regex:

```
myString = "apple costs 5 dollars each box"

myList = myString.split(" ")

storeString = []

for x in myList:

    if x == "apple":
        continue

    elif x == "each":
        break

    else:

        storeString.append(x)

# using list comprehension 
listToStr = ' '.join(map(str, storeString))

print(listToStr)
```

Output:

[image]